# Android - DataBinding with Preference Fragment

Tags: android, mvvm

I am working in a project to learn MVVM pattern. I used viewbinding from layout to auto generate binding classes. But when its come to Preference Fragment, I can't do the binding. I searched a lot, unfortunately nothing found.

Anyone please help me to find a way to code the Preference Fragment page in MVVM.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: check this link it will be help you- https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - DataBinding with Preference activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823020/android-databinding-with-preference-activity)

Answer (score 0):

> DataBinding for PreferenceScreen is still not supported.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136669/3422470